# How to handle expired token in next js middleware?

Tags: next.js, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am using cookies and jwt to authenticate my user and also protect my route in nextjs. Everything seems fine but when the token get expired the system take me to the login page to login again. But the process is, i have to use refresh token to get new access token and keep the user loggedin. But when i try to get the access token using axios i get the following error. And is that the right approach to authenticate user cause i find it quite hard

```
Error refreshing access token:  [AxiosError: There is no suitable adapter to dispatch the request since :
- adapter xhr is not supported by the environment
- adapter http is not available in the build] {
  message: 'There is no suitable adapter to dispatch the request since :\n- adapter xhr is not supported by the environment\n- adapter http is not available in the build',
  name: 'AxiosError',
  code: 'ERR_NOT_SUPPORT'
}
```

And this is my code i have done so far.Please give me some idea guys i get frustrated....

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { jwtVerify } from 'jose';
import axios from "axios";



async function refreshAccessToken(refresh: string | undefined): Promise<string | null> {
  const refreshTokenApi = `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HOST}${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_REFRESH_TOKEN_API}`
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(refreshTokenApi, { refresh });
    return response.data.accessToken;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error refreshing access token:", error);
    return null;
  }
}

export default async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const accessToken = request.cookies.get("access")?.value;
  const refreshToken = request.cookies.get("refresh")?.value;
  const secret_key = `${process.env.SECRET_KEY}`;

  if (!accessToken && request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/open-bo-account')) {
    request.cookies.clear();
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url));
  } else if (accessToken && request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/open-bo-account')) {
    try {
      const secret = new TextEncoder().encode(secret_key);
      const decodedToken = await jwtVerify(accessToken, secret);
      console.log(decodedToken);
      if (decodedToken) {
        return NextResponse.next();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("from error");
      console.log(errorJson);

      var errorJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(error));
      if (errorJson.code === 'ERR_JWT_EXPIRED') {
        request.cookies.clear();
        const newAccessToken = await refreshAccessToken(refreshToken);
        if (newAccessToken) {
          request.cookies.set("access", newAccessToken);
          return NextResponse.next();
        }
      }
      request.cookies.clear();
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: using fetch instead of axios will solve this problem